# How to get the last index of a specific item in a List?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
public class Ship
{
   private int shipId;
   private int position;
}

public class MessageOfShip{
    private List<Ship> ships=new ArrayList<Ship>();
}
```

The ships list is:

```
[shipID: 1 position: 10]
[shipID: 1 position: 20]
[shipID: 2 position: 10]
[shipID: 1 position: 30]
[shipID: 2 position: 20]
```

How can I get the last added item in the list of a specific shipId. Fox example the last added item of shipId1 is here `[shipID: 1 position: 30]`

Comment: Have you tried to think about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy implementation would be to check for any occurrence of the desired item, then iterate through to get the indexes of the desired item, overwriting the previous index if a new one is found. Return this index at the end.

```
int desiredIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < ships.size(); i++) {
    if (ships.get(i).equals("desiredStringToCheck") {  //it may not necessarily be a string
        desiredIndex = i;
    }
}
return desiredIndex;     //-1 signifies that the string is not found
```

An alternative solution (suggested by Andy, thanks!) is to iterate backwards and get the first occurrence of the desired item and return this value.

```
for (int i = (ships.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    if (ships.get(i).equals("desiredStringToCheck") {  //it may not necessarily be a string
        return i;
    }
}
return -1;       //If it doesn't return in the loop, meaning the string is not in the list
```

Edited to add checking for if the "desiredStringToCheck" doesn't exist in the list (Thanks Tom!).

Comment: Thank you! This will do!

Comment: Yeah here it is a class. So he need to write few getters.

Comment: Why not just iterate backwards, and return once you find a matching occurence?

Comment: I.. hadn't thought of that. Will update my solution with the backwards iteration now. Thanks Andy.

Comment: Are you sure you want to return index `0` if you can't find the searched element?

Comment: Well, I wasn't really meaning to return the index 0; it was more of giving the general idea as to how to obtain the desired index. Will edit it to add checks for if the item is not found (since I did indirectly assume at least one occurrence). Sorry about that.

Comment: You could also change `int desiredIndex = 0;` to `int desiredIndex = -1;`, because `-1` is often used for "not found".

Comment: Thank you guys! You really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the data backwards using `ListIterator`:

```
ListIterator<Ship> it = ships.listIterator(ships.size());
while (it.hasPrevious()) {
  int index = it.previousIndex();
  Ship previous = it.previous();
  if (/* somehow compare previous to the thing you are looking for */) {
    return index;
  }
}
```

An alternative way is to override `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Ship` class:

```
public class Ship
{
   private int shipId;
   private int position;

   @Override public int hashCode() {
     return Objects.hashCode(shipId, position);
   }

   @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
     if (other == this) {
       return true;
     }
     if (other instanceof Ship) {
       Ship o = (Ship) other;
       return shipId == o.shipId && position == o.position;
     }
     return false;
   }
}
```

Then just use `List.lastIndexOf`:

```
ships.lastIndexOf(new Ship(1, 10));
```